# Is " I need a one dance " grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

This song on the internet says.
" I need a one dance"

How can somebody use "one" and "a" together?
Is there another meaning for "one dance" as a phrase or something?

Here is the [link to the lyrics](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/drake/onedance.html)

Comment: This may help you, there's more [here](http://www.bustle.com/articles/152275-drakes-one-dance-lyrics-arent-really-about-dancing-but-thats-to-be-expected-from-drizzy) then the literal meaning of the words.  If "OT" is slang for "out-of-town", all bets are off for what "one dance" means...

Comment: Maybe it is written that way to fit the music timing? Something like when "a one and a two and a..." is used. In any case, artistic license says it is OK.

Comment: This is as close as you will get to a "meaning": https://www.bustle.com/articles/152275-drakes-one-dance-lyrics-arent-really-about-dancing-but-thats-to-be-expected-from-drizzy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not grammatically correct.  Music lyrics can reflect colloquial English spoken by the songwriter, but they often are completely made up, in order to fit a rhythm, to form an image, to create an impression, or simply to force a rhyme.  Poetry doesn't have to obey the standard grammar rules as long as you get a general sense of what the artist is trying to say.

I have no idea exactly what Drake means by "I need a one dance", so your guess is as good as mine.  That's poetry for you.

Comment: Poetry?  That's a very generous term for the lyrics.  Just out of curiosity, is there any point at which you would decide that lyrics don't qualify as poetry?  :-)

Comment: They're all poetry.  They're not all *good* poetry.  "Doggerel" has been around since ancient times, and clearly intends to stick around for a while longer.

Answer (score -2):

OT means out of town and a one dance is a showing of boobs.

Sometimes I don't get Drake.